# ASP.net set value to hidden form control

Tags: asp.net

In the ASP.net, I try to set a variable value to hidden field, but I get exception.

In the first output, it is correct. then I put it into hidden field, failed.

How to fix it ?

```
 user name: <%= User.Identity.Name %> // output is correct
    <form runat=Server>
    <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" value=<%= User.Identity.Name %> runat=Server />
    </form>
```

error

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give quote around your scriplet like given below.

```
 value='<%= User.Identity.Name %>'
```

**Change**

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" value=<%= User.Identity.Name %> runat=Server />
```

**To**

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" value='<%= User.Identity.Name %>' runat=Server />
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quotes: `value="<%= User.Identity.Name %>"`

If you can't set the value in the markup, do it in the codebehind:
In the `Page_Load()` put `HiddenField1.value = User.Identity.Name;`

Comment: I made this change, but looks like evalute it. <input type="hidden" name="HiddenField1" id="HiddenField1" value="&lt;%= User.Identity.Name %>" />

Comment: huh. I did some looking and it seems that you can't do this in the markup. Though you could always just set it in the `Page_Load()`.