# How to add a delete link to my table that will delete the record from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2010

I am essentially trying to add some clickable way to delete or edit entries from my table. These entries are all saved on an access database which populates the table. My biggest problem is that I am unsure on  how I can program the clickable method so that it saves which username I am trying to edit/delete. Any advice would be appreciated.

Relevant code:

main.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="main" %>
<%@ Reference Control="~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phUserInfoBox" />

    </div>

        <asp:Button id="login" runat="server"  Text="edit profile" onclick="btnRegister_click" />
        <asp:Button id="create" runat="server"  Text="logout" onclick="btnLogout_click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

main.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private OleDbConnection bookConn;
    private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = null;
    private String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='F:\test\Database21.accdb'; Persist Security Info=False;";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            bookConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
            bookConn.Open();
            oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT user_name, fname, lname  FROM profiles",bookConn);
            reader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                UserInfoBoxControl MyUserInfoBoxControl =(UserInfoBoxControl)LoadControl("UserInfoBoxControl.ascx");
                phUserInfoBox.Controls.Add(MyUserInfoBoxControl);
                MyUserInfoBoxControl.UserName = reader.GetString(0);
                MyUserInfoBoxControl.FirstName = reader.GetString(1);
                MyUserInfoBoxControl.LastName = reader.GetString(2);
            }
            bookConn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void btnRegister_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("myprofile.aspx");
    }

    protected void btnLogout_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
}
```

UserInfoBoxControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserInfoBoxControl" %>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>UserName</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= this.UserName %>  </td>
    <td><%= this.FirstName %></td>
    <td><%= this.LastName %></td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserInfoBoxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private string userName;
    private string fname;
    private string lname;


    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use model binding where you define a class type to show in the grid.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data/model-binding/updating-deleting-and-creating-data

Then you'll specify in your gridview with commands to update/delete/etc your records. In those methods you'll get the applicable info and delete. 
Ex grid:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="studentsGrid"
    ItemType="ContosoUniversityModelBinding.Models.Student" DataKeyNames="StudentID"
    SelectMethod="studentsGrid_GetData"
    UpdateMethod="studentsGrid_UpdateItem" DeleteMethod="studentsGrid_DeleteItem"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"  
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

and then notice how the id is passed in:

```
public void studentsGrid_DeleteItem(int studentID)
{
    using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
    {
        var item = new Student { StudentID = studentID };
        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", 
              String.Format("Item with id {0} no longer exists in the database.", studentID));
        }
    }
}
```

If this is your first time with web forms, I'd honestly look at going the MVC route and using MVC Scaffolding. You cannot use the Access database though with entity framework you'd need to use your OLEDB code directly like you did above (or not use access if that's an option)

Comment: Appreciate the advice. Unfortunately I have to use the access database since this is for school and I have to follow pretty specific guidelines. I also have to use a web user control and have to populate a table. So using a gridview isn't an option either. Unless I'm misunderstanding and I can somehow use a table and gridview.

Comment: good to know those details :)  If you want to keep this basic id avoid session. Session has perf issues and can be reset. Store the user id in a hidden field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582443/asp-net-set-value-to-hidden-form-control  then you can set the value when you load the record, and read it when you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. All I did was add a button in the web user control box and in the code behind created a new session variable.

UserInfoBoxControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserInfoBoxControl" %>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>UserName</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= this.UserName %>   </td>
    <td><%= this.FirstName %></td>
    <td><%= this.LastName %>   <asp:Button id="login" runat="server"  Text="edit user" onclick="btnEdit_click" /></td>


  </tr>


</table>
```

UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserInfoBoxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private string userName;
    private string fname;
    private string lname;


    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnEdit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UserNameMod"] = userName;

        Response.Redirect("userinfo.aspx");
    }
}
```